# GND pour for an AVR

Tags: grounding

AVR has two or multiple GND pins, and the GND pins are useful to provide ground references to other components. I have questions about the GND pour for such MCU with multiple GND pins.

Is it ideal to not connect the GND pins on an AVR to the same GND node? Should one have GND1, GND2, and so on? Does the 'star topology' mean actually separated tracks that end at one point?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, dedicate at least one plane to ground and drop vias right to that plane near each of the ground pins. Don't break that plane up with signal routing.

If you have analog ground pins dedicate a separate ground plane to digital and analog ground and connect them to one another by an array of vias in one place.

Another perspective that ignores your "ideal" requirement is it might not matter at all for your particular application. Because "it depends" (tm).

Comment: My questions is whether a star topology of grounding can be made in a PCB.

Comment: I would not use different ground "nets" for each AVR ground pin. Consider that they are electrically connected to one another on the die itself (which you can verify with a multimeter).

Comment: As for whether you *can* make a star ground on a PCB,  yes of course you can,  what would preclude it? You would need to use a fake two terminal component footprint to create the star junction to make the junction happen on a single page